# Magento 2.4.6 UPS Shipping Integration query

Tags: configuration, magento2, shipping-method, ups

We are integrating UPS shipment method in oru Magento application. We are facing the below issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJCiq.png)

We have checked with the UPS team and this is the response we have received from them "UPS doesn’t have any control on these settings and our API is open for all shipping methods and services."

**Admin configuration Part:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lro5a.png)

Kiondly Assist us this issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have integrated the UPS using live access user ID and password and Access slices number. but the shipping methods not shown the checkout page.

Comment: Any Idea about on my queries?